# How to extract an arithmetic operation from a string with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

In a Pandas DataFrame

```
>> df.head()

    A                               B             C
0   1    â#0.00 + "s=?0.07 + 'due0.93    rt@-[ 3.01
1   2    â#0.02 + "s=?0.16 + 'due0.82    rt@-[ 2.97
...
```

I would like to extract only the numeric values. Column `C` I can do with, e.g.,

```
>> extr = df['C'].str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)
>> df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(extr)
>> df.head()

    A                               B       C
0   1    â#0.00 + "s=?0.07 + 'due0.93    3.01
1   2    â#0.02 + "s=?0.16 + 'due0.82    2.97
...
```

but I have problems with the `B` column. How can I extract the `+` operations, as well as the floats? I tried

```
>> extr = df['B'].str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+)\+(\d+\.\d+)\+(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)
```

which I was hoping would give me something like

```
                    0
0    '0.00+0.07+0.93'
1    '0.02+0.16+0.82'
...
```

but instead it gives me three columns with `NaN` values in them:

```
       0      1      2
0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1    NaN    NaN    NaN
...
```

So how could I extract the whole arithmetic operations?

(Only the `+` operations are needed, and any other characters, such as `-`, can be ignored.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate approach using [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.findall(r'(\d+(?:.\d+)?)').agg('+'.join)
```

---

```
# print(df)
   A               B     C
0  1  0.00+0.07+0.93  3.01
1  2  0.02+0.16+0.82  2.97
```

`timeit` comparision of all the solutions:

```
df.shape
(20000, 4)

%%timeit -n100 @Shubham solution
df['B'].str.findall(r'(\d+(?:.\d+)?)').agg('+'.join)
31.9 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%%timeit -n100 @Rakesh solution
df["B"].str.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+)").str.join("+")
32.7 ms ± 1.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%%timeit -n100 @Sammy solution
["+".join(re.findall("(\d+\.?\d+)",entry)) for entry in df.B]
36.8 ms ± 431 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%%timeit -n100 @JudV solution
df['B'].str.replace(r'[^\d.+]', '')
59.7 ms ± 5.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @Judv I guess there should not be any difference but i will run `timeit` to make sure and let you know the results.

Comment: @Judv Got the `timeit` results and guess what they are almost same in terms of performance.

Comment: @JudV Its for one column `B`

Comment: Cool, seems like `replace` takes twice the time over `findall`. Too bad

Comment: this thows spanners into my notion that string processing within Pandas is slower than vanilla python. At least for this use case - Einstein's generalization is alive!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to run a [str join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on the extracted data, using `+` as the delimiter

```
import re

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}')


df['extract'] = ["+".join(re.findall("(\d+\.?\d+)",entry)) for entry in df.B]


    A                 B                  C         extract
0   1   â#0.00 + "s=?0.07 + 'due0.93    3.01    0.00+0.07+0.93
1   2   â#0.02 + "s=?0.16 + 'due0.82    2.97    0.02+0.16+0.82
```

Answer (score 1):

`Python` is not my forte but I'd use `replace` instead and do the operation for both columns, maybe look into:

```
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B','C']].replace(r'[^\d.+]', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   A               B     C
0  1  0.00+0.07+0.93  3.01
1  2  0.02+0.16+0.82  2.97
```

If it's just column `B` you are after than maybe simply use:

```
extr = df['B'].str.replace(r'[^\d.+]', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `str.findall` & `.str.join("+")`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"B": ["""â#0.00 + "s=?0.07 + 'due0.93""", """â#0.02 + "s=?0.16 + 'due0.82"""]})
df["Z"] = df["B"].str.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+)").str.join("+")

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                              B               Z
0  â#0.00 + "s=?0.07 + 'due0.93  0.00+0.07+0.93
1  â#0.02 + "s=?0.16 + 'due0.82  0.02+0.16+0.82
```